# Docker image running NodeJS won't connect to mongodb, locally code runs just fine

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker

I have a docker instance running the following code

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://testUser:<not giving password>@chatappcluster.qli90bl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1";

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});
async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

This code returns the following error

```
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN ac-1ycqaex-shard-00-00.qli90bl.mongodb.net
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/container/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-1ycqaex-shard-00-00.qli90bl.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-1ycqaex-shard-00-01.qli90bl.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-1ycqaex-shard-00-02.qli90bl.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-ejs9na-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Edit: The docker command is:

```
if [[ -d .git ]] && [[ 0 == "1" ]]; then git pull; fi; if [[ ! -z ${NODE_PACKAGES} ]]; then /usr/local/bin/npm install ${NODE_PACKAGES}; fi; if [[ ! -z ${UNNODE_PACKAGES} ]]; then /usr/local/bin/npm uninstall ${UNNODE_PACKAGES}; fi; if [ -f /home/container/package.json ]; then /usr/local/bin/npm install; fi; /usr/local/bin/node /home/container/test.js
```

On my local device it just says it connected succesfully, but on the docker image, running externally, it just doesn't wanna do the same

Comment: How do you initialize Docker with docker-compose?